# Computing Lesbegue Integral Using the definition of super level set

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Use the definition of the Lebesgue integral in terms of level sets to compute: $$\int_{\mathbb{R^2}} e^{-\mid x\mid^2} dx$$

Also, I am required to verify my answer using polar coordinates.

**My Approach**
Defining a super level set for $f(x)$ $$s_{f}(t):=\{x \in \mathbb{R^2}:f(x) \gt t\}$$
After solving I got these cases for $s_{f}(t)$
$$s_{f}(t)=\begin{cases}
\mathbb{R^2}, t \leq 0\\
0 \lt \mid x \mid \lt \sqrt{ln\mid 1/t \mid}, 0 \lt t \leq 1\\
\phi,t \gt 1
\end{cases}$$

My question: How to proceed forward and evaluate the Lebesgue Integral?

I know that the Lebesgue Integral formula that is : $$\int_{\mathbb{R^2}} f d\mu = \int_{0}^{\infty} \mu(s_f(t)) dt$$

$\mu$ is the measure.

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct integrand? The integral of $e^{|x|^2}$ over $\mathbb{R}^2$ diverges. Maybe you mean $e^{-|x|^2}$?

Comment: Yes, you are right @GyuEunLee. I have edited my super-level set. How to find the integral now?

Comment: No, I don’t have any idea about that thing. Can you help me understanding that concept and using that in this problem?

Comment: Lieb and Loss Analysis Book.

Comment: @Masacroso  thank you so much.

Comment: I got the answer and I have edited it. @Masacroso Using the Lebesgue integral formula : $$\int_{\mathbb{R^2}} f d\mu = \int_{0}^{\infty} \mu(s_f(t)) dt$$ Now, $\int_{0}^{\infty} \mu(s_f(t))=\int_{0}^{1} \mu(s_f(t))dt=\int_{0}^{1} \mu\{(0,\sqrt{ln(1/t)})\}dt=\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{ln(1/t)}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $t> 0$ we have that
$$
e^{-|x|^2}>t\iff -|x|^2>\ln t\iff |x|<\sqrt{-\ln t}\tag1
$$

Also we knows that (as is shown in the book)

$$
\int_{\Bbb R ^2}e^{-|x|^2}\mu_2(dx)=\int_{[0,\infty)}\mu_2(S_f(t))\; \mu_1(dt)=\int_0^\infty\mu_2(S_f(t))\; dt\tag2
$$

where $\mu_n$ is the Lebesgue measure in $\Bbb R^n$ and the RHS above is an *improper* integral of Riemann. By last note that

$$
\mu_2(S_f(t))=\mu_2\left(\left\{x\in \Bbb R ^2:e^{-|x|^2}>t\right\}\right)
=\begin{cases}
\infty ,& t=0\\
-\pi\ln t,& t\in(0,1)\\
0, &\text{ otherwise }
\end{cases}\tag3
$$
because the Lebesgue measure in $\Bbb R^2$ is the notion of area, in this case the area of circles of infinite radius (if $t=0$), finite radius (if $t\in(0,1)$), or the area of the empty set when $t\geqslant  1$, that in measure theory is set to zero. And so
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{\Bbb R ^2}e^{-|x|^2}\mu_2(dx)&=\int_{(0,1)}-\pi\ln t\,\mu_1(dt)\\
&=-\pi\lim_{s\to 0^+}\int_s^1\ln t\; dt\\
&=-\pi\lim_{s\to 0^+}[t\ln t-t]^{1}_{s}\\
&=\pi
\end{align*}\tag4
$$

Of course using polar coordinates we get the same answer, that is

$$
\int_{\Bbb R^2}e^{-|x|^2}\mu_2(dx)=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty re^{-r^2}\;dr\; d\alpha=-\pi\int_0^\infty d(e^{-r^2})=\pi\tag5
$$

because $[e^{-r^2}]'=-2re^{-r^2}$. Also we can use Fubini's theorem to evaluate this integral, that is, if $x:=(x_1,x_2)$ then

$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{\Bbb R^2}e^{-|x|^2}\mu_2(dx)&=\int_{\Bbb R^2}e^{-x_1^2-x_2^2}\mu_2(d(x_1,x_2))\\
&=\left(\int_{\Bbb R}e^{-x_1^2}\mu_1(dx_1)\right)\left(\int_{\Bbb R}e^{-x_2^2}\mu_1(dx_2)\right)\\
&=\left(\int_{\Bbb R}e^{-s^2}\mu_1(ds)\right)^2\\
&=(\sqrt\pi)^2\\
&=\pi
\end{align*}\tag6
$$

provided that $\int_{\Bbb R}e^{-s^2}\, \mu_1(ds)=\sqrt\pi$, as can be seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral).

Comment: What will be the value of the integral if we solve it using polar coordinates? I think the answers will be different.Try to check both the answers.

Comment: Why are using the finite limits, as it is defined for $\mathbb{R}?$

Comment: The value of this integral is $\sqrt{\pi}/2$

Comment: $\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{ln(1/t)}= \sqrt{\pi}/2$ If my process is right then it is not equal to your answer which is $\pi$

Comment: @Atul: your process is not right, because $\mu_2(S_f(t))=\pi\ln (2/t)\neq\sqrt{\ln(1/t)}$ for $t\in(0,1)$.

Comment: Can you give me a reference to the book from which I can study this?

Comment: @Atul, I added some other ways to handle this integral, including everything said in my previous comments (now deleted). There are plenty of books where you can study Lebesgue integration theory. A book that I was reading these days and I liked a lot is [this](http://measure.axler.net/), but there is a lot of other recommendations to study this topic, take also a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bbook-recommendation%5D+Lebesgue+integration).

Comment: for $t \in (0,1)$, can you explain to me how you got this value after applying the measure?

Comment: I already explained it in the answer: $\mu_2$ represent the notion of area, then the set $\{x\in\Bbb R^2: |x|<\sqrt{-\ln t}\}$ are the points of a circle centered at $(0,0)$ with radius $\sqrt{-\ln t}$, hence the Lebesgue measure of this set is $\pi\cdot (\sqrt{-\ln t})^2=-\pi\ln t$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.